# Order of custom menus in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

In my Django app, I've added a couple of custom menu entries to Django CMSes menu entries, using the `register_menu` decorator:

```
@menu_pool.register_menu
class MyMenu(Menu):
    def get_nodes(self, request):
        entries = []
        entries.append(NavigationNode('foo', '/bar', 1))
        ...
        return nodes
```

These menu entries are shown before any CMS menus, i.e. the list of menus returned from `{% show_menu %}` first produces my entries, then the entries created in the CMS.  I'd like my apps entries to come after the CMS entries, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that.

I was hoping that the ID would somehow affect the ordering, but it doesn't. Someone suggested that menus are created in the order the apps are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but moving my app to the very bottom didn't change the order, either.

### One solution

As suggested in the comments, a `Modifier` can not only change individual entries' attributes, but can also add, remove, or reorder entries.

```
from menus.base import Menu, Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool


@menu_pool.register_menu
class MyAppMenu(Menu):
    def get_nodes(self, request):
        nodes = []
        # ...
        return nodes


@menu_pool.register_modifier
class MyAppModifier(Modifier):
    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        if not post_cut:
            # ...
            # move our entries to the back of the list
            ours = []
            others = []
            for n in nodes:
                if n.namespace == 'MyAppMenu':
                    ours.append(n)
                else:
                    others.append(n)
            nodes = others + ours
        return nodes
```

The menu system uses the name of the class implementing `Menu` as the `namespace` attribute for the menu entries.  In the `Modifier`, I collect all entries added by my own app and put them at the end of the list.

Comment: You can modify a menu, check the docs; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html#navigation-modifiers

Comment: It wasn't obvious (to me) from the docs, but you can also reorder menus in the `modify()` method of a `Modifier` class.

Comment: Yeah pull requests for documentation improvements are something which the cms dev team will always welcome in my experience.